# Cargar datos a datagrid si no estan repetido

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Explicare lo que busco hacer, quiero cargar en mi datagrid el resultada de un query, este query lo ejecuto mediante un timer cada cierto tiempo.

Ahora por ejemplo si la primera vez que se ejecuto me trae una datos y ese dato lo paso al datagrid, cuando se vuelva a ejecutar el query si me trae el mismo dato(lo comparo con un campo llalado Folio, que esta en la columna1 del datagrid) entonces que no lo meta al datagrid(se entiende que no hubo cambios en la tabla), solo quiero agregarlo si el dato que trajo el query no esta repetido en el datagrid.

Saludos.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("miquery",conecReq);
        SqlDataReader readedata;
        conecReq.Open();
        readedata = command.ExecuteReader(); 
while(readedata.Read())
        {
            if (dataGridMisCotis.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                int fila = dataGridMisCotis.Rows.Add();
                dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column1"].Value = readedata.GetSqlInt32(0);
                dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column7"].Value = readedata.GetString(1);
                dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column6"].Value = readedata.GetString(2);
                dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column2"].Value = readedata.GetDateTime(3);
                dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column3"].Value = readedata.GetDateTime(4);
                dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column4"].Value = readedata.GetString(5);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridMisCotis.Rows)
                {
                    CheckFolio = dataGridMisCotis.Rows[item.Index].Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString();
                    int newID = readedata.GetInt32(0);

                    if (newID > Convert.ToInt32(CheckFolio) )
                    {
                        int fila = dataGridMisCotis.Rows.Add();
                        dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column1"].Value = readedata.GetSqlInt32(0);
                        dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column7"].Value = readedata.GetString(1);
                        dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column6"].Value = readedata.GetString(2);
                        dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column2"].Value = readedata.GetDateTime(3);
                        dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column3"].Value = readedata.GetDateTime(4);
                        dataGridMisCotis.Rows[fila].Cells["Column4"].Value = readedata.GetString(5);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Con este codigo cada vez que se vuelve a ejecutar me sigue agregando el ultimo dato.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que esta mal la logica de tu procedimiento:

Supongamos que en tu grilla guardaste los folios

```
1
2
3
```

Y ahora volves a consultar y vienen los folios

```
1
2
3
4
```

que pasa en tu programa? veamos:

```
while(readedata.Read())
{
    if (dataGridMisCotis.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridMisCotis.Rows)
        {
            CheckFolio = dataGridMisCotis.Rows[item.Index].Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString();
            int newID = readedata.GetInt32(0);
            if (newID > Convert.ToInt32(CheckFolio) )
            {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tu while, esta bien.. cuando esta vacia la grilla tambien.. pero que psas cuando no esta vacia??

Fijate...

viene el id 1... lo comparas asi:

```
if (newID > Convert.ToInt32(CheckFolio) )
```

con el id 1 en la grilla.. perfecto... y lo comparas con el 2.. y perfecto...

Pero en la siguiente vuelta...

Viene el id 2 en el reader..

Lo comparas con el id 1 en la grilla.. el dos es mayor.. lo guardas en la grilla.. error...

Vos no deberias comparar en cada vuelta, si no, por lo que vos decis, solo con el mayor de la grilla...

Tu mejor opcion, guarda el id mayor que tengas en la grilla.. y de paso usa ese id para solo traer lo nuevo ;)